# Lodash method for reversing key: values in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, lodash

Anyway one might be able to turn the following;

```
{
    "ID": "id"
    "Name": "name"
}
```

into;

```
{
    "id": "ID",
    "name": "Name"
}
```

Using lodash? I'm specifically looking for something along the lines of;

```
var newObj = _.reverseMap(oldObj);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs#invert

Comment: Thanks, does this also work with nested objects?

Comment: Reversing keys and values in an object sounds like something you would only want to if your program design is flawed. May I ask what this should be used for?

Comment: I am having to map a new data schematic to a legacy system, so it's not really poor program design, just a way for our new system to work with our existing one. So in this case, your assumption is flawed :)

Comment: @Tomalak after racking my brain for a while now and not seeing any other way of actually doing this mapping between two systems, with the upmost respect can you please explain how this is a flawed design?

Comment: I don't really know enough about what you do to suggest a solution outright. The thought process behind my comment is: An object is a collection of keys and values. Keys are the *handles* to data, they are *metadata*. They are not data themselves, or at least they should not be. If you have a system that treats keys as data (or data as keys), then that is a principal design flaw in my book. Can provide a live example of the objects you try to convert here?

Comment: In the case of mapping where the keys are handles to data on our system and the values the handles on another, you can perhaps see why this must be interchangeable. So we have a oneway mapping and without declaring two objects, it makes more sense to reverse the initial object right?

Comment: Well, then *both* are actually values and they should be represented that way: `var mapping = {keyA: "foo", keyB: "bar"}`, instead of `var mapping = {foo: "bar"}`. The second representation is an easy trap to fall into because it looks so convenient and short, but it will give you headaches like the one you are currently facing.

Comment: Yeah, that's what we have. Thought you might have a better way of doing it?

Comment: I thought I just outlined one in the comment. Apparently both of your systems use object keys as data - this is a design flaw in those two systems. Since you will hardly change them now, there is not a lot you can do. Take it more as something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: Please elaborate as this is simple data mapping, nothing overly complex and certainly something which is regularly done? How is this a design flaw? If so, perhaps a suggestion for how one might do it differently? They are just access keys.. it's a way of referencing each system's data. So I don't understand what you mean by they use them as data? In the same way a column is referenced in a database or record, we are simply mapping existing data structures to a new one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`invert`](https://lodash.com/docs#invert) works fine for flat objects, if you want it to be nested, you need something like this:

```js
var deepInvert = function(obj) {
    return _.transform(obj, function(res, val, key) {
        if(_.isPlainObject(val)) {
            res[key] = deepInvert(val);
        } else {
            res[val] = key;
        }
    });
};

//

var a = {
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
    nested: {
        a: 8,
        b: 9
    }
};

var b = deepInvert(a);
document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(b,0,3));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.2.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```